# How to change COLLADA(.dae) file to SceneKit(.scn) file programmatically Swift

Tags: swift, mobile, native, scenekit, arkit

```
COLLADA(.dae) , SceneKit(.scn)
```

I am working with `scenekit` and problem is there is an admin who will upload `.dae` file to server and i'll get that link in app and by using code i have to show it on camera. In running app for `.scn` file url it is working fine but for .dae file url it is generating an error **`COLLADA files are not supported on this platform.`**  so i want to convert .dae file to .scn file at run time. If anyone know any other source which can convert `.dae` file to `.scn` file kindly mention. By this source admin will upload `.scn` file to server after converting.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved thanks stackoverflow by using Model I/O swift concept

**Step1#**

```
// first need to download file to local directory
func downloadSceneTask(){
    
    //1. Get The URL Of The SCN File
    guard let url = URL(string: "Your_url") else { return }
    
    //2. Create The Download Session
    let downloadSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSession.shared.configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    
    //3. Create The Download Task & Run It
    let downloadTask = downloadSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

**Step2#**

Now i have url saved in my local device memory now i'll click anywhere in camera and load that local url in scene.

```
func addTapGestureToSceneView() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didReceiveTapGesture(_:)))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func didReceiveTapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: sceneView)
    guard let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: [.featurePoint, .estimatedHorizontalPlane]).first
        else { return }
    let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .featurePoint)

    // 2
    guard let result = results.first else {
        return
    }
    // 3
    let translation = result.worldTransform.translation
    self.translation = translation
    anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor!)
}
```

**Step3#**

My ViewDidLoad function be like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    addTapGestureToSceneView()
    downloadSceneTask()
}
```

**Step4#**

Add Protocol ARSCNViewDelegate

```
// Getting file from local directory and load
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
       guard !(anchor is ARPlaneAnchor) else { return }
       if let droneNode = loadModel() {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               node.addChildNode(droneNode)
           }
       }
   }

   func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
       let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
       let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
       return documentsDirectory

   }

   // Loads The SCNFile From The Documents Directory
   func loadModel() -> SCNNode? {
       //1. Get The Path Of The Downloaded File
       let downloadedScenePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("table.obj")
       let asset = MDLAsset(url: downloadedScenePath)
       let object = asset.object(at: 0)
       let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
       //7. Add It To The Scene
       return node

    }
}
```